# no post data returned when requesting headers CURLOPT_HEADER. PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

i am making a POST request using curl and PHP, sending a username/password array as a JSON object.

so far all is working wonderfully. now i wanted to read the headers so i can parse the cookie. i know i can use a file/jar and have tested that - works well. i want to not write a thing to disk.

so i flagged CURLOPT_HEADER as TRUE and i can parse the cookie value.

HOWEVER - the returned data is gone. totally gone... 
when i flag _HEADER FALSE - i see the response.

the code:

```
    $login_array = array('login' => array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
    $login_json = json_encode($login_array);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); <-- this line f***s it all up...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json")); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/test/token');

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code != 200) { /* do something */ }

    preg_match_all('|Set-Cookie: (.*);|U', $result, $content);    
    $cookies = implode(';', $content[1]);
    echo "cookie: $cookies<br>"; <-- thanks _HEADER for the cookie value

    $response = json_decode($result);
    $user_id = $response->user->id;
    echo 'user_id: ' . $user_id . '<br>'; <-- empty man... headers are on means body is off...
```

i've been digging through different posts and it seems the order of the opts makes a difference. tried moving them about - no luck.

thoughts?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$body=mb_substr($result, curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
$response = json_decode($body);
$user_id = $response->user->id;
echo 'user_id: ' . $user_id . '<br>';
```

Comment: this seems to be doing the trick - though please modify curl_get_info to curl_getinfo. so what is going on here? can you elaborate? thanks.

Comment: You used json_encode on $result but $result="header of the page" + "body of the page" because of "CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE" so you have to extract the body of the response page and applied json_encode to it.

Comment: exactly. for anyone following this thread - the issue here is that when you request the headers, you get them packed with the body.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_NOBODY,false)