# Parsing PHP CURL data

Tags: php, cookies, curl, response-headers

I have been messing with CURL for the past day and I cannot seem to figure out how to parse out the return data. I know I could write a REGEX to extract data from the response but it seems like there is some function I am probably missing. Here is what I would like to try and do.

I want to make POST to a different domain and get back 3 things
1. the response headers
2. the response data
3. a session cookie

Is there a way I can get those 3 things back separately? right now I just get back a plain text response with the response header and the response data. I would like to be able to do something like

```
$Response = curl_exec($Curl_Connection);
$ResponseData = $Response['Data'];
$ResponseHeader = $Response['Header'];
ResponseCookie = $Response['Cookie'];
```

Does curl provide anything like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I answered:

[no post data returned when requesting headers CURLOPT_HEADER. PHP CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836850/no-post-data-returned-when-requesting-headers-curlopt-header-php-curl/6836915#6836915)

Add:

```
curl_setopt($Curl_Connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

$Response = curl_exec($Curl_Connection);
$curlHeaderSize=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

$ResponseData = mb_substr($result, $curlHeaderSize);
$ResponseHeader = mb_substr($result, 0, $curlHeaderSize);

preg_match_all('|Set-Cookie: (.*);|U', $ResponseHeader, $content);   
$ResponseCookie = implode(';', $content[1]);
```

Comment: Yes this sort of answers my question. But it in a way does not. I still don't know how to get just the response headers while still having the body returned. The other part is the cookie is in the request header. How do I see that?

Comment: I love you and yes I am an idiot that has never used mb_substr :)

Answer (score 3):

According to the curl docs:

```
/* TRUE to include the header in the output. */
curl_setopt($Curl_Connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
```

So the header is added to the output of curl_exec command.  I've been spitting this out and I don't see any way to retrieve the header separately from the response body.  It gets worse when you start reading compressed output (zipped, inflated)

On top of that, it's a one big string, not an array, so in case you you want the header in a format like for example curl_getinfo brings back an array.

The easiest is to do this:

```
$backend_output = curl_exec($ch);
list( $backend_response_headers, $backend_response_body) 
      =  explode("\r\n\r\n", $backend_output, 2);
```

That will split those 2 up, but you end up with a string for the response header, not an array which would be so much more helpful.  Now making an arrray from that isn't so evident, even with a regex as you can't split on for example something simple like /(\w)\s:(\w)/ as ':' can occur in certain fields.  It would be very cool if curl would offer the headers seperately but so far as I go through the docs, it doesn't seem to be there.

Concerning your session cookies, I believe you need to use CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION = true option for that, but I have less experience on cookies as I hardly ever have the professional need to use them.  Good luck

update: The headers you can parse with http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php or a custom function from the user comment section if you lack pecl.